# Is there a statistical test to check a difference in coefficient of variation (relative standard deviation) between groups in python?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, coefficients

I calculated a coefficient of variation (CV) for weights in three different groups. **My aim is to check if one of the groups has a lower variability than others**. I plotted the results on a strip plot and visually I can tell that one of the groups has lower CV scores than other groups (which translates into a lower variability). However, I'd like to confirm my finding using a statistical test. I found the following tests for measuring CV difference between groups:

- **the ‘Asymptotic test for the equality of coefficients of variation from k populations’ (Feltz and Miller 1996)**
- **the ‘Modified signed-likelihood ratio test (SLRT) for equality of CVs’ (Krishnamoorthy and Lee 2014)**

Unfortunately I could only find R packages for running them. Is there any way of running these tests in Python? Are you aware of any other tests/methods of empirically checking if the difference between CVs between groups is significant?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a ready-made test you might either use bootstrapping, or reverse engineer the coefficient of variation to identify the component from each data point and do a non-parametric test of those individual components across groups.

For [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) a test of whether group A has lower CV than group B:

- Create a resampled variation of group A by drawing *n* random values from group A (with replacement, so the same value may be drawn more than once), where *n* is the original size of group A.
- Create a similar resampled variation of group B, the same size as the original group B.
- Calculate CV for the resampled groups.
- Repeat the resampling several thousand times, keeping track of how often CV is higher for resampled group B than resampled group A.
- If the CV for resampled group B is rarely higher than for resampled group A (small *p*-value), then we could conclude that CV for group A is significantly less than for group B.

Another plausible option might be to calculate squared relative deviation of each data point, and use a non-parametric test to compare groups.

- [CV is calculated as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation#Examples_of_misuse) sample SD / sample mean = root mean squared relative deviation (but using N-1 instead of N when calculating the mean).
- If group A has mean *xbar*, then squared relative deviation for point *x* in group A is the square of *(x - xbar)/xbar*.  This is the contribution for point *x* to the calculation of CV for group A.
- At least if the group sizes are the same, then we can compare CVs indirectly by comparing the squared relative deviation scores for different groups using a non-parametric test of differences between means.